# Iteratively add values in array and replace values

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

Suppose I have an array like this - `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`

I need to utilise `streams` and need an array - `[1,2,3,5,8]` which is adding values of the element one by one.

What is the best way to do this with Java `Streams` or while taking input? (With minimum complexity)

Comment: Stream operations are meant to be performed on each element independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to not use streams but use the [Arrays.parallelPrefix](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix-int:A-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) method with a lambda to add consecutive values.

```
int[] vv = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3};
Arrays.parallelPrefix(vv, (a,b)-> a + b);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vv));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Here is your Stream solution.  There may be a better way using streams but this uses nested streams to compute repetitive sums and return them in an array.

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, vv.length).map(
        i -> IntStream.range(0, i+1).map(k -> vv[k]).sum())
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // Prints as before.
```